# JQuery .trigger('click') doesn't work first time on mobile / iOS safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

I am creating a game which will automatically play a sound file when a user taps on a flip card.  It works perfectly across all desktop browsers and Chrome for Android.

The play button is placed within the flip card and when the user taps on the "top" of the card it uses JQuery .trigger('click') to fake the play button press.

It will work on iOS Safari, but the user needs to click the play button once for it to then work for the rest of the session.  Here is a link to the game itself - http://dev2.gluestudio.co.uk/flipCards/flipCards.html

Here is my code for playing the audio automatically:

```
var clickedCard = $(this);
setTimeout(function(){
  if(clickedCard.find('div.mgcard-show').find('button.questions').length != 0){
     var cardToBeClicked = clickedCard.find('div.mgcard-show').find('button.questions');
     $(cardToBeClicked).trigger('click');
 }
} ,1000);
```

Here is the code for the play icon (as part of a much larger loop)

```
 $('body').append('<audio id="player' + i + '" src="audio/'+firstQuestion+'"></audio>');
 $('#flip-card-area').append('<li class="match'+i+'"><button class="questions" onclick="document.getElementById(\'player' + i + '\').play()"><img class ="playIcon" src="./img/play_icon.png"></button></li>')
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue and make the play work first time on mobile browsers?

Comment: Try to use a simple `.on('click', function(){});`